# C# Custom Universal Scroll Bar

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I would like to make a custom scrollbar (change color, etc...) that can easily be added to already existing C# controls. All the examples that I have found only work for the control that they were designed for.

What I am thinking is:

```
public class ColoredScrollBar : UserControl {

    private ScrollBar scrollbar;

    public ColoredScrollBar(ScrollBar scrollbar){

        this.scrollbar = scrollbar;
    }
    // OnPaint
    // Then draw scrollbar with same size and location as 
    // the scrollbar

}
```

So basically I want to draw right on top of the existing scroll bar. Giving it the custom look that I want.

For this to work I would need to then be able to pass events throw the ColoredScrollBar to the real scroll bar that is below.

This way my ColoredScrollBar could work for every C# control, because it uses the already impended scroll bar to do all the moving and calculations.

Is it possible to pass event to the control below. If it is can you show how? If there is a better way to create a universal scroll bar (that can be easily added to all existing c# controls), I would love to here it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Winforms? I can't imagine that thsi will worke so easily.  Some controls (eg TextBox) will let you suppress their own scrollbars but when you add yours to their controls collection but the Text will go under it then. Other will not give you control. Nice idea, though, good luck!